# Radio Button Group Produce a Zero Value When Form Method=POST

Tags: php, html, post, radio-button, form-submit

I have a group of radio buttons placed in a form with method post. But anytime the form is post the value from the radio button is zero. Below is the code

```html
 <form method="POST" action='insert_per.php'>
<table >
<caption>
     Grant Permissions
            </caption>
   <thead>
            <tr>
       
                <th class="center"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Email</strong></th>
    <?PHP if($_SESSION['user_group'] == 63){
    echo '<th class="center"><strong>System Admin</strong></th>';
                echo '<th class="center"><strong>Admin</strong></th>';
    echo '<th class="center"><strong>User</strong></th>';         
    } ?>
     <th class="center"><strong></strong></th>
              </tr>
     </thead>
            <?php
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // output data of each row
                while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                    <tr>
         <td border="0" type="hidden"  style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value=<?php echo $rows['member_id']; ?></td>   
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
      
      <?PHP if($_SESSION['user_group'] == 63){ ?>
            <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="system admin"
            <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 31 )?'checked':'' ?>></input> </td>
      <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="admin"
           <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 15 )?'checked':'' ?> ></input> </td>
         <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="user"
           <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 1 )?'checked':'' ?> ></input> </td> <?PHP } ?>        
            
                         <td class="center"><button name="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT">submit</button></td>         
                           </tr>               
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?> 
</table>
    </form>
```

Below is the code for the insert_per.php

```html
echo "this is the gp  "+ $_POST['gp'];
echo "this is the gp  "+ $_POST['hidden'];

try{
 $stmt= $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `members_groups` SET `group_id`=(SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE 
                                       group_name = ? ) WHERE member_id = ?"); 

$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['gp'] , PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(2 , $_POST['hidden'] , PDO::PARAM_INT); 
   
if($stmt->execute()) {    
   echo "  the privilege was granted successfully ".'<BR>';
   echo "<a href='user_acc.php'>View result</a>";
}  
} catch(PDOException $e)
{
 echo "An error occured  ".$e->getMessage();
 
}
```

The radio buttons are expected to produce one of the following values 
"system admin" 
"admin" 
"user" 
but it always produces zero "0" value.

Comment: Please add insert_per.php content to your question

Comment: When you post data did you take any error message ?

Comment: No error message was given